# IISExpress ClientCertificate Setup Steps

Tags: certificate, iis-express, client-certificates

I am trying to configure a simple web site to require client certificates on IISExpress.

My configuration is according to this archived [jasonrshaver.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20111201044809/http://www.jasonrshaver.com/?tag=/IIS+Express) post.

```xml
<site name="XXXX" id="3">
 <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
  <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="XXXX" />
 </application>
 <bindings>
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:65360:localhost" />
  <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
 </bindings>
</site>
...
<access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" />
...
<iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true">
</iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
```

It is a simple MVC4 Web App that outputs the ClientCertificate data.

The problem is that when I browse to https I am not prompted for a certificate in browser. I do have 4 certificates that can be used; they are configured in Chrome

Any help appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: where is that code going

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a certificate problem, not a IISExpress configuration problem.

I had no certificates that could be used for client authentication.
After installing a certificate with Intended Purposes  everything worked fine.

So the above configuration works just fine.

Comment: What was wrong with the certificate, I'm having a similar issue

Comment: I have similar problem. CA is installed on separate virtual machine, it is accessible, CA root cert is installed in Trusted CA list on dev machine and still, when I make a call to web api 2 RESTapi service, Request.GetClientCertificate() returns null. Any ideas what caould be wrong?

Comment: if i remember correctly the problem i was not using a client certificate: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2012/02/17/client-certificates-vs-server-certificates/