# HttpRequestMessage.GetClientCertificate is null when certificate is being set on client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-express, client-certificates

I've set up a WebAPI service to require https and open to accept a client certificate.  The SSL part is working fine.  I'm using the WebRequestHandler to attach a certificate (a real one, not test cert) to the request, but when I access request.GetClientCertificate in the WebAPI controller, the certificate is null.

The ssl cert is bound to the port using "netsh http add sslcert" with the clientcertnegotiation=enable parameter.

I'm using IISExpress, and modified the applicationhost.config by adding `<access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" />` to the security node, and setting `<clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true" />` under the authentication node.

I don't get any errors, just null.

My only clue is when I bring up the WebAPI in the browser, I'm prompted for a ClientCertificate, and the one I'm adding to the WebRequestHandler in code is not in the list.

What are the requirements for a certificate to be used as a client certificate?  This question ([IISExpress ClientCertificate Setup Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752386/iisexpress-clientcertificate-setup-steps)) implies that may be my problem.

Answer (score 1):

To require certs you need to set SslRequireCert in addition to SslNegotiateCert. The mapping is typically not needed.

The requirement for client certs are that the issuer of that cert must a trusted issuer (from a service point of view) meaning in the "Trusted CA" list...and the issuer cert must include an intended purpose of "client authentication".

Comment: If I add SslRequireCert, my request doesn't even make it to the server.  My cert isn't making it.  And it does have client authentication with the purpose.

Comment: Well - then you don't have a cert in the user store that is considered trusted by the server. Are you sure the CA cert is in the right store and all that?

Comment: An old article I wrote: http://leastprivilege.com/2005/11/25/iis6-and-client-certificates/

Comment: That could be a clue.  As I'd said, I get a dialog when I debug the server, but my certificates aren't in the dialog.  The certificate I want to send has Client Authentication usage, but the root CA for it does not.  However, I also created a test cert according to these instructions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949057.aspx), and still get failure.  FYI - I am not looking to have this work with Active Directory.  This is a cert on a smart card.